# Kotlin: Setting default when annotating a Java library with Nullability

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to annotate a library properly for good Kotlin support. That means, Kotlin knows
about a non-null Java type and uses Kotlin type to represent it. Non null parameters and
return values is a useful default, so I'd like to establish it formally within my API. According to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html we can use JSR305 annotations to set a default, e.g. via:

```
@Nonnull
@TypeQualifierDefault({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface NonNullApi {
}
```

However, as stated in the reference, by default Kotlin only warns for JSR305 annotations.
As also stated, we need to enable strict mode:

```
@Nonnull
@TypeQualifierDefault({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@UnderMigration(status = MigrationStatus.STRICT)
public @interface NonNullApi {
}
```

But:

> The strict value should be considered experimental (more checks may be added to it in the future).

It seems JSR305 has the best support, and lets us establish reasonable defaults, but, doesn't have the desired effect unless enabling a experimental feature.
What is the current best approach?

Comment: You're asking this as a library author ("How to force library clients to not pass nulls to my API") or as a library user ("How to ensure that I accidentally haven't passed nulls to library API")?

Comment: I am asking as a library author. https://github.com/cache2k/cache2k/issues/125

Comment: Actually, `MigrationStatus.STRICT` is not an experimental (aka [opt-in](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/opt-in-requirements.html)) feature, but a [`@Deprecated`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/0764a065e8303a63daf0ccd6b3bab2a5cede6380/libraries/tools/kotlin-annotations-jvm/src/kotlin/annotations/jvm/MigrationStatus.java). So it will take effect by default, and nor you neither your library clients need to somehow explicitly enable it (although they may explicitly disable it with `-Xjsr305=under-migration:ignore`). Why not just go with this approach? What downsides do you see?

Comment: The default is `WARN` not `STRICT`, I tried it. Spring / Spring users have the same problem: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-kotlin.html#boot-features-kotlin-null-safety

Comment: You mean after adding `@UnderMigration(status = MigrationStatus.STRICT)` line it still gives warnings instead of compilation errors (when `null` is passed to parameter marked with `@NonNullApi` annotation)?

Comment: No. @UnderMigration(status = MigrationStatus.STRICT) does result in errors, as I like to achieve. However, its deprecated and said to be experimental. Should I use it or not? What is the alternative?

Comment: According to git history, it was created this way. Not completly sure about rationale behind this, but highly likely it's related to the fact that JSR-305 is not an approved standard itself (it's still in [dormant](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) status). Worst that could happen - is that you use it, and then it would be removed from Kotlin. But I believe it won't happen before there would be provided some alternative and a migration plan. I don't know about any feature-parity alternative at this moment (except rewrite library in Kotlin completely, or at least its public API part).